# Why is enthalpy change at constant pressure not only internal energy change?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Okay so this might seem a bit Weird but the formula for change in enthalpy has been given the following way-

∆H=∆U+∆PV

so in this case when we say ∆V is zero we get that ∆PV  is also zero and thus ∆H=∆U. But when we say pressure is constant, my teacher simply takes out the pressure term outside the delta function because it's constant and writes,

∆H=∆U+P∆V

Why does he do this? Why can't this also result in the expression we get from constant volume? Plz explain

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117611/discussion-on-question-by-krish-vasa-why-is-enthalpy-change-at-constant-pressure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be thought of as H = U + PV, and operating with delta on all terms may be treated as differentiating the whole equation. So for the “PV” term, you need to use the product rule.

You end up P(dV) + V(dP) and if pressure is constant (which it generally is, so it’s a fair assumption), dP=0 and you’re left with P(dV).

(And to your point, if volume is constant, dV=0 and that just means that at constant pressure and constant volume, the change in enthalpy is equal to the change in the internal energy of the system.)